# RCTView.nativeID error in armeabi-v7a devices only

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to React Native. I have created an app which builds and runs on all Android devices/emulators, except the `armeabi-v7a` ones.

The error log I see while running the Application in Android `armeabi-v7a` is:

[image]

My `build.gradle` file:

```js
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


import com.android.build.OutputFile



apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionName = "2.1.1"

       
        versionCode 115
        versionName "2.0.5"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }

        // TODO: Maybe this can help with the "libglog_init.so" not found not found issue
//        packagingOptions {
//            exclude "lib/armeabi-v7a/libglog_init.so"
//        }

        //TODO: Possibly no longer required.
        // packagingOptions {
        //     exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libgnustl_shared.so"
        // }
    }
    
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    // TODO: Possibly not required
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.getRequested().getGroup() == 'com.google.android.gms') {
            details.useVersion('9.8.0')
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // From node_modules
    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1')
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    compile project(':react-native-video')
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile project(':react-native-fs')
    compile project(':tipsi-stripe')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':bugsnag-react-native')
    compile project(':react-native-orientation')
    compile project(':react-native-media-kit')
    compile(project(':react-native-maps')){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
    compile project(':react-native-image-resizer')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-i18n')
    compile project(':react-native-geocoder')
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.4'
    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1') {
        force = true
    }
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

Where am I going wrong? What do I need to do to run the App in all devices?

P.S.: I am using React Native version `0.49.0`